# Having centered equations with non centered text on the same line

Tags: spacing, formatting, alignment

Is it possible to achieve multiple lines of equations, where the equation is centered, but text annotations on the right has no influence on the centering?

Instead of:

```
    E = mc^2     Famous Equation by Einstein
         a^2 + b^2 = c^2     Pythagoras
```

Have it be something similar to:

```
        E = mc^2     Famous Equation by Einstein
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2     Pythagoras
```

When i use gather or similar multi line environments, having a \text command within them influences the centering of the entire line and putting text outside of these environments places the text on a new line.

I have also tried implementing the text as tags, within a gather environment, its close but it requires very large page margins to render "properly" due to some strict spacing requirements.

Comment: As long as the equations and text don't overlap, an array could work, setting the left-hand column to be centered, and I'd be inclined to left-align the text on the right.

Comment: Please provide more information about how you're typesetting the "text annotations on the right" at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength\cw

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\[\settowidth\cw{Famous Equation by Einstein}
\begin{array}{c @{\qquad\qquad} p{\cw}}
E=mc^2          &   Famous Equation by Einstein \\
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 &   Pythagoras
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possibility.  Note that the text or the right is also aligned.

The width (4em) is **not** critical, so long as it is the same in each row and prevents the text from overlapping the math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \mathmakebox[4em][c]{E=mc^2} && \text{Famous Equation by Einstein}\\
& \mathmakebox[4em][c]{a^2 + b^2 = c^2} && \text{Pythagoras}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c,m]Q[l,m]},column{2}={cmd=\text}}
E = mc^2        & Famous Equation by Einstein \\
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 & Pythagoras                  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c,m]Q[l,m]},column{2}={cmd=\text,leftsep=40pt}}
E = mc^2        & Famous Equation by Einstein \\
a^2 + b^2 = c^2 & Pythagoras                  \\
\end{tblr}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is align the annotations as made in the others answer, but as this is not what you asked for, and the questioner rules ... `:)`

If you want annotations  without displace the centered equations just add text but not any horizontal space (`\rlap` or a `\makebox` of `0pt`, for instance).

Assuming that you may also want to avoid long annotations going outside the margin you can use a `\parbox` for the remaining space (calculated  with the `linegoal` package. Warning: this require **two** (1+1=2) compilations).

Guessing also that you want to place the equations aligned among themselves, but not in the center of the page to free some space for the annotations, you can add a negative `\hspace` in display mode (set by trial and error, the same to every equation) or use an array in inline mode (so the array is not centered). The MWE showed the second case:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{lipsum,parskip}
\usepackage{linegoal,array}

\newcommand\eqnote[2]{#1\rlap{\hspace{1cm}\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedright #2}}}
%\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\parskip1em

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\noindent\(
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\eqnote{E=mc^2}{Famous Equation by Einstein}\\      
\eqnote{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}{Pythagoras}\\ 
\eqnote{i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi(x,t) = \left [ - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x,t)\right ] \Psi(x,t).}{Schrödinger Wave Equation}\\
\eqnote{1 + 1 = 11}{Alternative maths in a unary numeral system.}\\ 
\eqnote{1=1}{\lipsum[3][1-1]}\\      
\eqnote{1+1+1=1+1+1}{\lipsum[3][1-1]}\\      
\eqnote{1+1+1+1+1+1=1+1+1+1+1+1}{\lipsum[3][1-1]}\\      
\end{array}
\)

\lipsum[2][1-3]
    
\end{document}
```